# SharePoint linked datasource

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have created a linked datasource in sharepoint designer by joining two sharepoint lists. Can anyone tell me how can I access this linked datasource programmatically?

Regards,
Sharmila

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint designer, it seems to me that linked datasources show up in the list of available libraries when you are trying to build a data view web part or similar constructs.

So maybe try to access your linked datasource like you would any other list or document library?